# karma jasmine not executing all tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

so i have 6 karma jasmine tests, in one file i have 3, which im testing all my factories

the test file for the factory is as followed

```
describe('Quiz Factories', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {

        //Ensure angular modules available
        beforeEach(module('geafApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_counter_) {
            counter = _counter_;
        }));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_answer_sheet_) {
            answer_sheet = _answer_sheet_;
        }));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_questions_) {
            questions = _questions_;
        }));

    });

    it('it should return a number', function () {
        expect(counter).toBeNumber();
    });

    it('it should return an empty object', function () {
        expect(answer_sheet).toBeEmptyObject();
    });

    it('it should return an empty object', function () {
        expect(questions).toHaveObject(answers);
    });

});
```

in my console log its showing executed 4 of 6

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 6 SUCCESS (0.004 secs
>   / 0.029 secs)

So for some reason after the first it 'it' in the factory test file its skipping over the other two, even though there is no failures and all are contained in a beforeEach

Comment: show your other files. Also, you can combine your three beforeEach injectcts into just one beforeEach.

Comment: which other files do you need to see? the tests or application,

combining the injectors still results in same behaviour

Comment: You are showing only three of the 6 tests. Where are the rest of them? Are any of the other tests running? What file is that 4th test coming from? show your karma.config as well.

Comment: the other three tests are on controllers, the 4th one being executed is the first test in this factory test, i know this because if i change that test to an expression that fails it shows in the log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well then, let's start here. Change your file to this to clear a few things up and see if it goes away. You also need to define **answers** in the last test.

```
describe('Quiz Factories', function() {

  var counter, answerSheet, questions;

  beforeEach( function(){
    module( 'geafApp' );

    inject( function( _counter_, _answer_sheet_, _questions_ ){
      counter = _counter_;
      answerSheet = _answer_sheet_;
      questions = _questions_;
    });
  });

  describe( 'when a question is asked', function(){
    it( 'should return a number', function(){
      expect( counter ).toBeNumber();
    });

    it( 'should return an empty object', function(){
      expect( answerSheet ).toBeEmptyObject();
    });

    it( 'should return an empty object', function(){
      expect( questions ).toHaveObject( answers ); // ??? answers is not defined!!!!
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Further to the accepted answer, which is a much better structure for the tests anyway, I have found reproducible scenario for this:  nested `beforeEach` sections found in a test cause Karma to stop running any further Jasmine tests.  You can see in the question that it is indeed the case - the `beforeEach`'s for the injects are within an outer `beforeEach`.

As part of a merge, one of our `beforeEach` lines that loads the module under test had been moved within a later `beforeEach` inadvertently.  This was preventing all tests after that one running.  Karma was reporting that x of y tests were running where x was 65 less than y, but that the test run was successful and there were none skipped.

So if you encounter this, check your report output for the last 'successfully' execute test (I say successfully in quotes as it's probably the one causing the issue) and see if that doesn't have nested `beforeEach`'s in it.

Answer (score 1):

Also relevant:

It can also happen it there is an exception thrown before the tests hit any `expect` - this will not cause the test to be reported as failed - as it was never run. It *will* be shown as a reduced number of running tests. You can check your console logs for errors in that case.

Comment: This is what was happening to me. At the same time I also had [this issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/issues/47#issuecomment-54721356) which made it so that my console logs weren't displayed.